# Best way to put a kotlin program on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kotlin

I have written a duel simulator in Kotlin for an online video game. The user has to input the combat levels of both players, then how many duels they want to simulate, and then click start and it will recreate the duels and return the win% and other stats to the user. It takes <2 seconds to run 100,000 simulations on my laptop.

I really need help working out how to get this onto a website though because I am only now learning html, css, and javascript. So what should I do, the options I have come across so far are

1. turn it into an applet/application (but I read this is deprecated in java?) and then embed it into my webpage, or
2. convert it into JavaScript and have it run on the users browser (but I worry this will be slow, or look laggy, or allow someone else to simply copy the entire thing?), or
3. just have a form on my page that sends the details the user enters to a server (?) where it runs and then returns the result to the user whilst the user sees some pretty loading animation?

So am I on the right track or way off here? Any advice will be appreciated, like pointers on what to learn and where to look for good information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 3 is probably the best if you want to make sure it runs quickly and nicely, without lagging, being slow or even making the browser crash, regardless of the number of people accessing your website

Create a HTML form, send the data to a server and have it return the result.
Then, you can control the resources your server has to match the demand - when you get more users, upgrade the server, no-one will notice and everything will keep running smoothly.

When demand gets even higher than a single server can handle, you can have multiple servers with a load-balancer that spreads user requests between servers, to make sure no server gets too busy with requests.

Comment: Thank you, could you go into more detail about servers? I'm finding information about web servers and other advertisements. What type of server do I need? How does my code run on a server, is it always running or does it wait for a request and then run the kotlin (in a virtual machine?) and give me the result? I feel like I'm asking a lot so do you know of any good resources I could learn from?

Comment: Type of server - any.. really. basically you need any machine that can accept HTTP/HTTPS requests, run code and respond. 
You can even use your own computer as a server. 

Get something that can handle HTTP requests on your servers (Spring or Apache for example)
Then make it run whatever code you need it to, and return the result, when requested. 

A good [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) for setting up a REST server with Spring